# laravel controller query response time is slower than the phpmyadmin query runtime

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin

I am using laravel 5.0 and i included the below code in my TestingController:

```
public function test(){
    $user = DB::table('user_table')->get();
}
```

I used the url : http://localhost:8081/test to load the empty screen and the load time is about 1.38 second for the query. The load time is slower than the runtime time of the query in phpmyadmin which is about 0.16ms. why got such big different in load time for laravel when compare to phpmyadmin? does there any way to reduce the query load time in laravel?

Comment: You can use caching? But as i've just said on a fairly similar question Laravel is a framework so there's a bunch of classes etc being pulled in prior to the query whereas phpmyadmin is working directly in the DB - that will always be faster

Comment: @Andy Holmes I tried use the php artisan route:cache and php artisan config:cache but the query load time still almost the same. does there any other configuration can be set to reduce the query load time in laravel?

Comment: How many records do you have in your table ? By default, phpmyadmin has a LIMIT clause, so if you are loading a lot of data while phpmyadmin is only loading 25 records or so, it's normal phpmyadmin takes less time to load the data

Comment: @Tugdual My table only have 3 records. I tried load all 3 records in screen and in phpmyadmin, the load time is different.

Answer (score 0):

Use ELequent ORM . than it will be more Faster . DB facade work better on large database

```
$user = new User;

$user->name = 'John';

$user->save();
```

Comment: i would like to load the user data from database and  show it in the table in my screen. I used the eloquent User model like : $user = User::all(); but the load time still around 1.35 second